# DataGridView "Second" Load is much slower

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an unbound datagridview view.  The first load always runs very fast but the second load is about 20 times slower.

I do the following everytime and if I remove this code the second and subsequent loads are fast (unfortunately I must keep this color logic):

```
            for (int ri = 0; ri < pdgv.Rows.Count; ri++)
            {
                for (int ci = 0; ci < pdgv.Columns.Count; ci++)
                {
                    if (pdgv.Columns[ci].Frozen)
                    {
                        pdgv[ci, ri].Style.BackColor = v.Frozen_BackColor;
                        pdgv[ci, ri].Style.ForeColor = v.Frozen_ForeColor;
                        pdgv[ci, ri].Style.Font = v.Frozen_Font;
                        if (pdgv[ci, ri].OwningColumn.Name.StartsWith("yn_") &&
                            pdgv[ci, ri].Value != null &&
                            pdgv[ci, ri].Value.ToString() == "1")
                        {
                            pdgv[ci, ri].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                            pdgv[ci, ri].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
                        }
                    }
                    if (pdgv.Columns[ci].ReadOnly)
                    {
                        pdgv[ci, ri].Style.BackColor = v.ReadOnly_BackColor;
                        pdgv[ci, ri].Style.ForeColor = v.ReadOnly_ForeColor;
                        pdgv[ci, ri].Style.Font = v.ReadOnly_Font;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you move this color logic to `ItemDatabound` or any other `data binding event` of your `grid` ??

Comment: I think ItemDatabound uses System.Web.UI.WebControls which is ASP.NET not C#/Winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dispose and rebuild the datagridview before loading the second time and it is as fast as the first load.